# If $T$ is a projection, then $R(T)=N(T)^\perp$ if and only if $N(T)=R(T)^\perp$.

Tags: linear-algebra

In Friedberg's Linear Algebra textbook, a linear operator $T$ on an inner product space $V$ is said to be an orthogonal projection if $T$ is a projection, and
$$\tag{1}R(T)=N(T)^\perp$$
and
$$\tag{2}N(T)=R(T)^\perp\mbox{,}$$ where $S^\perp$ denotes the orthogonal complement of $S$. It is shown at once that when $V$ is finite-dimensional, (1) is equivalent to (2).

I think that the equivalence is valid even if $V$ is infinite-dimensional. For suppose (1) holds. It suffices to show that $N(T)=N(T)^\perp\left.\right.^\perp$. That $N(T)\subset N(T)^\perp\left.\right.^\perp$ is evident. Since $T$ is a projection, $V=R(T)\oplus N(T)$, hence every vector $v\in V$ can be expressed uniquely as a sum of $v_1\in R(T)$ and $v_2\in N(T)$. If $v\not\in N(T)$, then $v_1\not=0$, thus
$$\left<v,v_1\right>=\lVert v_1\rVert^2>0\mbox{.}$$
This together with (1) shows that $v\not\in N(T)^\perp\left.\right.^\perp$; therefore $N(T)^\perp\left.\right.^\perp\subset N(T)$. Similarly, (2) implies (1).

Am I right?

Comment: I made a substantial edit to my answer below; the example I gave was wrong along with its conclusion. I'm notifying you via this comment as you may wish to reconsider accepting my answer in case you were looking for something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is correct. Namely, since $T^2 = T$ it easily follows $$V =R(T) \dotplus N(T)$$
and if you assume $(1)$, then $R(T) \perp N(T)$ so the  sum is in fact orthogonal:
$$V =R(T) \oplus N(T).$$
In particular, both subspaces $N(T)$ and $R(T)$ are closed and hence $(2)$ follows.

Moreover, $T$ in fact must be bounded. Namely, for any $x \in V$ we have $Tx \perp x - Tx$ so
$$\|Tx\|^2 \le \|Tx\|^2 + \|x-Tx\|^2 = \|Tx+(x-Tx)\|^2 = \|x\|^2.$$

**Note:** The following example is wrong as the hermitian form $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ defined below is not an inner product.

Consider $c_{00}$, the space of all finitely-supported sequences in $\Bbb{C}$ equipped with the (incomplete) inner product
$$\langle (x_n)_n,(y_n)_n\rangle := \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(x_n\overline{y_n} + nx_{2n}\overline{y_{2n-1}} + nx_{2n-1}\overline{y_{2n}}\right).$$
Consider
$$T : c_{00} \to c_{00}, \quad T(x_n)_n := \left(x_1+x_2, 0, x_3+2x_4, 0, x_5+3x_6, 0,\ldots\right).$$
Then $T^2 = T$ and
$$R(T) = \operatorname{span}\{e_{2n-1} : n \in \Bbb{N}\}, \quad N(T) = \operatorname{span}\{e_{2n}-ne_{2n-1} : n \in \Bbb{N}\}$$
and we have the orthogonal sum
$$c_{00} = R(T) \oplus N(T).$$
However, $Te_{2n} = ne_{2n-1}$ for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$ so $T$ is unbounded.